# Discountinous function has a zero.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $g$ is continous function, $f+g$ is non-decreasing and $f(a)>0>f(b)$. Prove that we can find a point $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.
Given that $f+g$ is non-decreasing I know that it has at most countable number of points where it's non continous and all of them are jump discontinuities so left and right limit in each point exists. Given that right and left limit of $f+g$ and of $g$ exists we see that also $f$ has right and left limit in each point. However I'm stuck how to proceed with that proof.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually an interesting problem. One way is repeating one of the proofs of the IVT. Denote $a_1=a, b_1=b$, and let $h_1=\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$. If $f(h_1)=0$ then we are done. If $f(h_1)>0$ then we denote the interval $[h_1,b_1]$ by $[a_2,b_2]$, and if $f(h_1)<0$, denote the interval $[a_1,h_1]$ by $[a_2, b_2]$. In either case, we have $f(a_2)>0>f(b_2)$. Now let $h_2=\frac{a_2+b_2}{2}$ and repeat the process. If $f(h_2)=0$ we are done, if $f(h_2)>0$ then define $[a_3,b_3]=[h_2,b_2]$, if $f(h_2)<0$ define $[a_3,b_3]=[a_2,h_2]$. In either case, $f(a_3)>0>f(b_3)$. Now continue in a similar way.

If at some point we have $f(h_n)=0$ then we are done. Otherwise, we have a decreasing sequence of intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ such that $f(a_n)>0>f(b_n)$, and their lengths tend to zero. By Cantor's intersection theorem, there is a unique point $c\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]$, and it satisfies $c=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$. Now, since $f(a_n)>0$, for each $n$ we have:

$g(a_n)<f(a_n)+g(a_n)\leq f(c)+g(c)$

Since $g$ is continuous, we have $g(a_n)\to g(c)$, and hence $g(c)\leq f(c)+g(c)$, i.e $f(c)\geq 0$. Similarly, $f(b_n)<0$, and so:

$f(c)+g(c)\leq f(b_n)+g(b_n)<g(b_n)$

Again, $g(b_n)\to g(c)$, and hence $f(c)+g(c)\leq g(c)$, i.e $f(c)\leq 0$. Thus, $f(c)=0$.

Comment: Very nice proof +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof.

**Lemma**

$f$ has only upward jump discontinuities i.e. $\lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) \le f(c)$ for all $c \in (a,b]$ and $\lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) \ge f(c)$ for all $c \in [a, b)$. (In particular, the one-sided limits exist in $(-\infty, \infty]$.)

**Proof**

We note that if $h$ is non-decreasing, then $\lim_{x \to c^{-}}h(x) = \sup_{x<c} h(x) \le h(c)$. Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to c^{-}} (f(x) +g(x)) \ge f(c) + g(c)$$

But $\lim_{x \to c^{-}}g(x) = g(c)$ by the continuity of $g$. Therefore, we deduce the result as claimed for $x \to c^-$. Similarly for the other limit.

**Proposition**

$f$ has a zero in $[a,b]$.

**Proof**

Let $\hat{f}$ be defined by $\hat{f}(x) = \inf_{y \le x} f(y)$ for all $x$ such that this infimum is not $-\infty$. Then, $\hat{f}$ is continuous since $f$ only has upward jump discontinuities. Further, $f(a) > 0$ implies $\hat{f}(a) >0$ and $f(b) <0$ implies $\exists c : \hat{f}(c) <0$. Therefore, $\hat{f}$ has a zero by the IVT.

Let $z$ be the greatest zero for $\hat{f}$; this exists by continuity. We claim that this is also a zero for $f$.

Suppose not. By definition of $z$, we have $\hat{f}(y) <0$ for all $y > z$.

$$\iff \inf_{x \le y} f(x) < 0 \text{ for all } y > z$$

$$\iff  \forall y > z, \; \exists z < x \le y : f(x) < 0 $$

$$\implies \lim_{y \to z^+} f(y) \le 0$$

(For the last implication, note that the limit always exists, so we can find the limit along a subsequence $x_n \downarrow z$ with $f(x_n) < 0$ for each $n$ by the above.)

Then, by the lemma, $f(z) \le \lim_{y \to z^+} f(y)$, so we find that $f(z) \le 0$.

On the other hand, $f(z) \ge \hat{f}(z) =0$.

Hence, $f(z) = 0$, as required.